# How to inject MySQL database into the project folder

Tags: java, mysql, database

How to put the MySQL database in the folder with the java project so that the program connects and behaves appropriately with this database, if it is possible of course.

Comment: If you want a file-based database you should use a file-based database :) like sqlite.

Comment: Otherwise, this is a strange requirement which you may want to explain, so people can give you more appropriate answers.

Comment: finally i used sqlite, but now i have trouble [SQLITE_BUSY]  The database file is locked (database is locked), idk how fix it

Comment: 1) it's a bit hard to help you without knowing what you're doing. 2) that is a different question than the one you originally asked. My suggestion is to delete the question about mysql and create a new one about sqlite. But remember to post all the necessary info in the new question (use [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922) as a guideline) or it *will* get closed.

Comment: Also, it's possible sqlite is not the correct tool to use. It was just an example since you didn't specify what you needed.

Comment: my problem is: i must create a app with db, and i must send it to my teacher, my app working without any problems in my pc, but crush in another machine, because i use MySQL database, which located locally in my pc, have u any adequate options to my problem? is possible insert my database to the project folder?

Comment: was mysql part of the assignment? if so you just need to assume your professor has a local instance on their machine, at which point you just need to have your program connect to your professor's instance, verify if the tables you need exist and create them if necessary. Really, there are too many variables *we don't know* here to give you a meaningful answer.

Comment: yes, unfortunately the MySQL was part of the task, the whole question is the ability to put the database inside the project and connect to it from there?

Comment: That's not how mysql works. If you are expected to connect to a database, whoever runs the program is expected to provide a database.

Comment: I understand you, thank you very much for your understanding and patience)